# basic authentication does not work even for correct credentials

Tags: tomcat7, web.xml, jaas, jdbcrealm

I am trying to configure Tomcat 7 JDBC realm configuration. 
I have followed this tutorial completely:
http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-a-jdbc-realm-with-tomcat-and-mysql.html

I get the basic authentication pop-up, but even if I enter correct credentials, user is not authenticated.
I don't get any error message.

Tutorial specifies Tomcat 5.5 but I am using Tomcat 7.
I have just changed the `connectionPasword` and `connectionName` and the name of dynamic web project.

Here is `server.xml` JDBC realm configuration

```xml
    <Realm  className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
            driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tomcat_realm"
            connectionName="root" 
            connectionPassword="root"
            userTable="tomcat_users" 
            userNameCol="user_name" 
            userCredCol="password"
            userRoleTable="tomcat_users_roles" 
            roleNameCol="role_name" />
```

Here is `web.xml`

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>test.TestServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Wildcard means whole app requires authentication</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>dude</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>

    <user-data-constraint>
        <!-- transport-guarantee can be CONFIDENTIAL, INTEGRAL, or NONE -->
        <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
</login-config>
```

All I can see is, I get this message regarding security:

```
Security role name dude used in an <auth-constraint> without being defined in a <security-role>
```

Can you please help me sort this out? Is this issue related to Tomcat 7?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the [Java Servlet Spec](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr315/), you need to define the `dude` role as a security role. To do this, add the `<security-role>` element to your `web.xml`, as shown below:

```xml
<servlet>
<!-- ... -->
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Wildcard means whole app requires authentication</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>dude</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
<!-- ... -->
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
     <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
</login-config>

<security-role>
    <role-name>dude</role-name>
</security-role>
```

This would allow `GET`/`POST` requests to any user having the `dude` role.

I'll suggest you don't include the `<http-method>` elements as they don't work as you might expect. Including this element for `GET` and `POST` means that the security constrain applies only to these two methods; any other method is allowed. Here is what the Servlet Spec says:

> The sub-element web-resource-collection identifies a subset of the resources and HTTP methods on those resources within a Web application to which a security constraint applies.

See [this reference](http://software-security.sans.org/blog/2010/08/11/security-misconfigurations-java-webxml-files/) for details.

Comment: Thank you for the useful information but it doesn't seem to work. I get the same problem. The user is not getting authenticated even if I enter correct credentials.
Also, I don't see any log in tomcat. How to generate logs in tomcat?

Comment: Do you still see the original error you mentioned: role name dude not defined in a <security-role>, or a different one?

Comment: Thanks man that hepled.
Now I don't get that message anymore. 
At first, it didn't work even after you suggested the change, but then, I replaced tomcat and configured once again then it started working. Thanks for the answer it was helpful :) 
I will upvote as soon as I get the privilege :)

Comment: glad to hear that is now working for you. I'll encourage you also to consider eliminating the GET and POST method from the security constrains as including them means that the security constrain applies only to these two methods so, by default, other methods might be enabled and would not need the user to authenticate.

Comment: Federico Raggi Yes sure, I had idea about it, I was just trying to implement the tomcat 7 jaas example from the tutorial and I've done necessary changes for http-method in my real project.
Thanks again for the help :) It is highly appreciated